# matplotlib multiple overlapping xlabels in 2 levels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to find a solution to a situation where I have multiple xlabels in the plot, which I cannot give up any. 
The problem is that the xlabels are running on each other, making the plot not readable (as in subplot`(1,1)`)
I was wondering if I can somehow make each second label in another hight (as in the example attached)

[image]

What I had in mind:
[image: o]

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Two options: (a) Use major and minor ticks and labels, change the offset of one of those. (b) Set individual transforms for the ticklabel texts, every second one should get an offset transform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two approaches

- Add a positive rotation to the ticks/labels: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html
- Add two new-lines to every even x-label. The code is taken from https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-bar-stacked-py and modified with a list comprehension that does this (and also modified so the labels are kind of big, like yours)

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# call this function in xticks parameters
def transform_xlabels(xlabels):
    return ('\n\n%s' % label if i % 2 else label for i, label in enumerate(xlabels))


N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
menStd = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)
womenStd = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
ind = np.arange(N)    # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

p1 = plt.bar(ind, menMeans, width, yerr=menStd)
p2 = plt.bar(ind, womenMeans, width,
             bottom=menMeans, yerr=womenStd)

plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('Scores by group')
test = 'G1 abc \ndaido misco iso'
xlabels = ('G1 %s' % test, 'G2 %s' % test, 'G3 %s'  % test, 'G4 %s'  % test, 'G5 %s'  % test)

# function is called
plt.xticks(ind, transform_xlabels(xlabels))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 81, 10))
plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0]), ('Men', 'Women'))

plt.show()
```

Output

[image: bar graph]