# Matplotlib identify if xlabels "run" on each other

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using matplotlib I have multiple xlabels (which I cannot give up any)
After consulting this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60399815/matplotlib-multiple-overlapping-xlabels-in-2-levels/60400202#60400202) I've decided to add a second line of xlabels for the spacing.
Unfortunately, while for some graphs it is enough, for some there are still too many labels, and I need a different solution.

My idea was to somehow "identify" that the xlabels run on each other - and if so, create a third line of xlabels, and so forth, Until no overlapping labels.
Can it be done?[image]

Edit:
It's not perferct, and doesn't answer directly the question of my post, but using rotation I got something reasonable I can work with
`ax.set_xticklabels(labels, fontsize=8,rotation=20)`
[image]

Comment: Why not numbering the plots and adding a label (or caption) where you identify what each number represents?

Comment: The graphs are dynamic, meaning I do not know in advance how many labels I'll have

Comment: What about rotating the axes? Your plots will be horizontal instead of vertical and you may be likely to put the xlabels you want (since your ylabels wont overlap).

Comment: You can also change the labels to have a '\n' in them to get them written on two (or more) lines.

Answer (score 1):

What if you rotate the xticklabels by the settings within plot()?

Comment: Wasn't aware you can rotate by "soft" angles, edited with an example, thanks